# Choose only certain files to merge in Local Repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to `Git` & `GitHub` so, getting really confused between its usage.

I am working on a project where I have cloned a project (GPL/GNU Licensed) from GitHub e.g.

```
 https://github.com/myrepo/myrepo.git
```

Later on, I made some changes as per my need like changing some HTML & CSS with some images etc.

Now I have found some important updates to the Repo (Master Branch) on GitHub but if I Fetch then as per my understanding, with latest updated files, it will also fetch & merge my modified files too.

My question, is there any way where I can see what files are updated/added in latest Repo release and choose only certain files to be merged with my local repository?

Comment: That's not the way to work. Revisions are created on a project so that each revision is a fully-contained step forward in the project. You should consider your changes the same way. If you think that your changes are not really ready to be made into a revision just yet, then stash them, pull the changes from upstream and then pop them out of the stash so that you can continue working.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thank you for your kind suggestions of Stash, as I said I am new to Git so didn't knew about stash.

Comment: no problem.... it's one of the best features in git.... along with rebase, detached HEAD, branches are pointers... it's a long etc, actually :-)